# Android - Custom Dialog throws NullPointerException when more than one button is defined

Tags: java, android, exception, mobile, nullpointerexception

Here's the code that defines my custom dialog. When I show this dialog, it throws a NullPointerException at the commented line.

```
    protected Dialog onCreateDialog (int id) {
    Dialog dialog = null;
        switch (id) {
        case DIALOG_SUCCESS_ID:

            Context thisContext = this;

            dialog = new Dialog(thisContext);

            dialog.setContentView(R.layout.win_dialog);
            dialog.setTitle("Stage One");

            TextView timeScore = (TextView) dialog.findViewById(R.id.TimeScore);
            timeScore.setText (elapsedTimeSec + "s");
            TextView bestScore = (TextView) dialog.findViewById(R.id.BestScore);
            bestScore.setText ("Best Score: (n/a)");

            Button retry = (Button) dialog.findViewById(R.id.Retry);
            retry.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                public void onClick (View v) {
                    Intent retry = new Intent(v.getContext(), LevelOne.class);
                    startActivityForResult(retry, 0);
                    finish();
                }
            });

            Button menu = (Button) dialog.findViewById (R.id.ReturnToMenu);

            //Throws NullPointerException at this line
            menu.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                public void onClick (View v) {
                    Intent menu = new Intent(v.getContext(), Menu.class);
                    startActivityForResult(menu, 0);
                    finish();
                }
            });
            break;
        case DIALOG_GAMEOVER_ID:
            break;
        default:
            dialog = null;
        }
        return dialog;
}
```

But when I remove my menu button and the menu.SetOnClickListener() method, it works fine! My retry button also works without a hitch. Why can't I add more than one button? Why does it throw the exception?

Comment: It's hard to tell without seeing your resource files, but are you trying to add two buttons directly to a View or to a layout that doesn't support multiple child objects?

Comment: It'll help if you also post your layout file for the dialog

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It looks like `dialog.findViewById (R.id.ReturnToMenu);` is returning null. Can you check that you actually have a button with the correct ID? I'd guess that there is a typo somewhere in your "return to menu" button ID.